# while automation unable to click on link because of horizontal scrolling is not working

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation

I am automating webpage using JavaScript but while automating I can't click on links which are hidden behind scroll. I wrote code for horizontal scroll, but it's not working. So can you help with how to scroll horizontally so that i can click on the link

here is my code:

```
LinkPath = sampleUtility.getXpathEntity(driver,
              exlXpath.get("LNK_SAMPLE_DATASET").toString(), 
              DSetName, 
              exlXpath.get("LNK_DATASET_DELETE").toString());
Thread.sleep(min_wt);

WebElement box = driver.findElement(
                        By.xpath(exlXpath.get("LNK_SAMPLE_DATASET").toString()));
try{
  try{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(LinkPath.toString())).click();
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollRight();", box);
  }catch(Exception e){
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollRight();", box);
  }
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(LinkPath.toString())).click();
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath looks at xhtml tags, not the UI, so scrolling to the left or right on your web page won't help selenium find your link. You need to double check your xpath. [There's a tool for firefox that can build the entire command for you](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) .. I'd suggest using that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of Javascript which worked for me a lot better than scrollRight() and scrollLeft()

```
private void scrollToElement(WebElement element){
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
}
```

Hope it helps!